# Spring Web: Loading ModelMap from HTTP query parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

From [spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-view) about redirecting:

> All model attributes are exposed as HTTP query parameters

After redirect, how can I load ModelMap from HTTP query parameters. Can I avoid adding attributes manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the usual Spring MVC Binding, either using `@RequestParam("modelName")` or by passing in a backing form to be bound by Spring `requestMappedMethod(MyBackingForm form, Model model)`

If you are using Spring 3.1, you can also flashmaps at the point of redirect, then you can actually retrieve it directly from the model in the redirected controller.

```
fromRedirectMethod(..., RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs){
     redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("myAttr1","myAttrVal1").addFlashAttribute("myAttr2", "myAttrVal2");
...perform redirect
}

inRedirectedMethod(@ModelAttribute("myAttr1") myAttr1.., Model model){
    model.asMap().get("myAttr2");.
}
```